# How to use phone as an USB Wi-Fi adapter?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, internet, wifi-hotspot, usb-tethering, sony-ericsson-xperia-x8

I would like to use my SE Xperia 8 with 2.1 as an usb wifi adapter to my PC. What I would like to do is set it to access point mode and share my ADSL internet with my laptop through wifi.

I would connect the phone via an usb cable and I would like to be able to route and share my pc's internet through it to and back from my laptop.

I don't mind if the firmware must be changed as I have an other phone. But I prefer if there is easier/more convenient way to do this. On the pcs I'm also flexible about OSes.

How could I use my phone as an wifi adapter?

**EDIT** To make it more clear, here is what I mean:

I have:

- "PC A" with internet over ADSL. no wifi.
- my phone, it has an usb cable and a wifi chipset.
- "PC B" with wifi

What I would like to do us **to use PC A's internet on PC B, with the help of my phone**.
Connect Internet to PC A, then connect my phone to PC A, then connect PC B to my phone via Wifi, and use PC A's internet on PC B.

Internet >>> Adsl modem >>> ethernet cable >>> PC A >>> USB cable >>> phone >>> wifi >>> PC B

Comment: [PDANet+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pdanet) or [Klink](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.faveset.klink) would probably work for you. There are a number of apps that have a computer counterpart for sharing phone's connection over USB.

Comment: I just added the `usb-tethering` tag to your question, as that's what it's all about. Take a look at the [most frequented questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb-tethering?sort=faq) of this tag, and your question will find an answer :)

Comment: @Izzy I edited my question because I think it is not a duplicate. I don' tunderstand how reverse tethering helps me, as I cannot share it with PC B. Or... should I set it up, does all what remain is to make the phone an acces point (how?)? Will it forward all ports? I'd like to use ftp, ssh and https.

Comment: "Reverse tethering" is the part "PC A -> USB -> phone", which is what your question described. "phone -> WiFi -> PC B" would be "WiFi Hotspot" (added that tag to your question). Everything else is outside the scope of our site ;) So I'd say check those two first, and see whether they can work together (i.e. if the tethered phone can play hotspot at the same time).

Comment: @Izzy I see, very informative, thank you! I'll ask another Q (if must) when I have a result, so this can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Yepp, I guess that's the best choice. Above should get you started, and when you get stuck, simply ask a specific question on what you've done and where you've got stuck. We'll be glad to help you out then, of course!

Comment: Nice Question....